# Why the data start scrolling horizontally when data is coming from server?

Tags: android, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am working on jquery and jquery mobile .I am facing one simple but it too complicated issue .I have one div in which I append my server data.
In that div i insert style (width example 40%).When I inserted static data it working fine in other word data come in new line when width complete.
But when the data coming from server it start scrolling horizontally.
Take Example If i have data Static.
data look like this

> Hi this is demo
>   No I will come
>   next morning

But when data come from server it show like thsi

> Hi this is demo(see upto here and you can scroll your data) No I will come next morning
>   I am facing this problem in android .

Here is my code.

```
<div id="test" style="width:40%"></div>
```

```js
$('#test').append(result)
```

I am getting result from server like this

```
     console.log("result"+result);
08-15 21:32:20.898: I/Web Console(5635): result&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{mrr}&nbsp;distanced&nbsp;himself&nbsp;in&nbsp;May&nbsp;of&nbsp;2010&nbsp;following&nbsp;the&nbsp;prohibited&nbsp;practice.
08-15 21:32:20.898: I/Web Console(5635): :876
08-15 21:32:20.906: D/CordovaLog(5635): 


  var data  = result.replace("&nbsp;", " ");
     console.log("After result"+result);



After result&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{mrr}&nbsp;distanced&nbsp;himself&nbsp;in&nbsp;May&nbsp;of&nbsp;2010&nbsp;following&nbsp;the&nbsp;prohibited&nbsp;practice.
08-15 21:32:20.906: I/Web Console(5635): After result&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{mrr}&nbsp;distanced&nbsp;himself&nbsp;in&nbsp;May&nbsp;of&nbsp;2010&nbsp;following&nbsp;the&nbsp;prohibited&nbsp;practice.
```

Comment: are spaces being replaced with `&nbsp;` (read non-breaking space) before your server returns it?

Comment: I will paste what i am getting from server ..wait

Comment: Well there's your problem. you need the server to NOT replace the spaces with &nbsp;.

Comment: Is this server problem ?We can't do any thing in java script file?

Comment: You could, but fixing it with javascript is backwards. a regexp would fixit it with javascript, but i wouldn't go that route unless i had absolutely no access to the server code.

Comment: But for now can we solve this issue.Because I can learn.i need this data come only in fixed width not horizontal scrolling

Comment: Write a regexp that finds all occurences of `&nbsp;` and apply it to the returned data using .replace() to replace `"&nbsp;"` with `" "`.

Comment: It solve the problem of data to come next line?

Comment: Yes, &nbsp; is "non-breaking space" in that it won't break to the next line when it gets to the end.

Comment: ok doing tell you in 5 min..

Comment: Not getting result &nbsp not replace..same result coming as before..:(

Comment: any other solution..?